# Hbase remotely connecting to standalone instance

Tags: hbase

I have been trying to setup HBase for the first time. I am able to successfully run the native Hbase shell on the server. But I am not able to connect remotely via a client.

I start Hbase using the following command on host:
`/home/kirill/hbase/hbase-1.2.5/bin/start-hbase.sh`

To connect from a client, I run the following in Python (Anaconda):

```
>>> import happybase
>>> co = happybase.Connection('192.168.0.18',2181)
>>> co.tables()
```

I get the following error after trying to list tables with `co.tables()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\happybase\connection.py", line 242, in tables
    names = self.client.getTableNames()
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\thrift.py", line 198, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\thrift.py", line 210, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\protocol\binary.py", line 372, in read_message_begin
    self.trans, strict=self.strict_read)
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\protocol\binary.py", line 164, in read_message_begin
    sz = unpack_i32(inbuf.read(4))
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 32, in read
    return readall(self._read, sz)
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 14, in readall
    chunk = read_fn(sz - have)
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\transport\buffered\__init__.py", line 39, in _read
    self._rbuf = BytesIO(self._trans.read(max(sz, self._buf_size)))
  File "C:\soft\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\thriftpy\transport\socket.py", line 125, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(message='TSocket read 0 bytes', type=4)
```

## Here are last 3 lines from Hbase log:

It says that connection from 192.168.0.11 (client IP) is accepted, but immediately after that it throws an `Exception causing close of session`:

```
2017-06-06 10:48:10,634 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /192.168.0.11:58052
2017-06-06 10:48:11,841 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error -2147418111
2017-06-06 10:48:11,842 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /192.168.0.11:58052 (no session established for client)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the host setup:

## Hbase setup:

**Host running Hbase**: Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-31-generic x86_64)

**path to Hbase bin folder**: /home/kirill/hbase/hbase-1.2.5/bin

**IP of host**: 192.168.0.18

**conf/hbase-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///home/kirill/hbase/hbase-1.2.5/</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/kirill/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>192.168.0.18</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

**/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.0.18    ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue opened for `happybase` python package: https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/issues/6

It works now.
2 things needed to be done differently:

1. hbase has to be started with Thrift like so: 
   `/home/kirill/hbase/hbase-1.2.5/bin/hbase thrift start -threadpool`
2. I should not be connecting to port specified under `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` which is 2181, but rather the default port that is used in the happybase `Connection()` function, which I believe is 9090.

I have also changed my /etc/hosts file to this:

`192.168.0.18    ubuntu.ubuntu-domain ubuntu localhost`